# Why is my implementation of sqlite3 + python (using tkinter) slow to display the whole database at once?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, text-widget

I'm working with a database with an '.sqlite' extension using SQLite3, Python, and Tkinter. I created a function to display the entire database when the program starts up using a spreadsheet-like interface with text widgets:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('duff1.sqlite')

c = conn.cursor()

# Creating root
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Table')

# make frame
frame0 = tk.Frame(root, bd=2)

# make display canvas
dpcanvas = tk.Canvas(frame0)

# make display frame
displayframe = tk.Frame(dpcanvas, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN)

def pdp():
    data = fetch()
    for index, dat in enumerate(data):
        t0 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t0.insert(tk.END, dat[0])
        t0.grid(row = index + 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)
        t1 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t1.insert(tk.END, dat[1])
        t1.grid(row = index + 1, column = 1, sticky = tk.W)
        t2 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t2.insert(tk.END, dat[2])
        t2.grid(row=index + 1, column = 2, sticky=tk.W)
        t3 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t3.insert(tk.END, dat[3])
        t3.grid(row=index + 1, column=3, sticky=tk.W)
        t4 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t4.insert(tk.END, dat[4])
        t4.grid(row=index + 1, column=4, sticky=tk.W)
        t5 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t5.insert(tk.END, dat[5])
        t5.grid(row=index + 1, column=5, sticky=tk.W)
        t6 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t6.insert(tk.END, dat[6])
        t6.grid(row=index + 1, column=6, sticky=tk.W)
        t7 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t7.insert(tk.END, dat[7])
        t7.grid(row=index + 1, column=7, sticky=tk.W)
        t8 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t8.insert(tk.END, dat[8])
        t8.grid(row=index + 1, column=8, sticky=tk.W)
        t9 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t9.insert(tk.END, dat[9])
        t9.grid(row=index + 1, column=9, sticky=tk.W)
        t10 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t10.insert(tk.END, dat[10])
        t10.grid(row=index + 1, column=10, sticky=tk.W)
        t11 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t11.insert(tk.END, dat[11])
        t11.grid(row=index + 1, column=11, sticky=tk.W)
        t12 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t12.insert(tk.END, dat[12])
        t12.grid(row=index + 1, column=12, sticky=tk.W)
        t13 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t13.insert(tk.END, dat[13])
        t13.grid(row=index + 1, column=13, sticky=tk.W)
        t14 = tk.Text(displayframe, height=1, width=13, relief=tk.SOLID, bd=1,     font='helvetica 11')
        t14.insert(tk.END, dat[14])
        t14.grid(row=index + 1, column=14, sticky=tk.W)


def fetch():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM 'duff'")
    return c.fetchall()


pdp()


frame0.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor='nw', fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

displayframe.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor='nw', fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

dpcanvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor='nw', fill=tk.Y, expand=2)

displayframe.update_idletasks()

dpcanvas.create_window((4, 4), window=displayframe, anchor='nw')

# main loop
root.mainloop()
```

It seems to work well with up to around 500 rows -though it takes a few minutes to load-, but I'm working with databases much larger than that. As an example, a database with 500 rows takes 3 minutes to load; one with 1600 takes around 16, and the python app crashes when closed.

Is my code too inefficient? is it a problem with the way tkinter works? I remember having done something similar using labels and the code running way faster, however I need to use text because I want the user to be able to 'navigate' inside the boxes, which sometimes have a dozen or so lines and several characters per line.

I looked for an answer to my problem indicating that the version of sqlite in Python 2.7 was particularly slow, however I'm using python 3.6.1 and the versions of SQLite and Tkinter that came with it.

I read another possible answer that involved creating indexes which could speed up queries, but I haven't gotten to that part yet.

Comment: Did you profile it?

Comment: 3 minutes to load a database seems like a very long time. Profile your code to be sure its SQLite like MSeifert suggests. If you have simple column-able data, you might find it easier and faster to use Pandas and load the data from CSV into a DataFrame. Pandas can handle many millions of rows quite quickly.